# How to add claims to the HttpContext User on sign in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

This post may be long, but will have all the pertinent detail required for an answer.

I have been searching, and found that many others have as well, for the proper methodology to add claims to the HttpContext User so that those claims can be retrieved when needed, using Razor, in a view.

For example,

In the default Asp.Net Core 2.0 web application, the _LoginPartial has code that displays the users email. If I wanted to change that to the users full name (this assumes the registration process includes the first and last name entries, with the appropriate changes to the ApplicationUser class)

```
 // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    ...balance of code removed for brevity
}
```

I would want to add a claim on the User for their full name and gender to use instead of the UserManager method currently employed in the default app. (And others down the road)

Current default wep app code

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log out</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
...code removed for brevity
}
```

What I am hoping to accomplish;
Replacing this,

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
```

with this

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @((ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity).GetSpecificClaim("avatarUrl")!</a>
```

Note: GetSpecificClaim is an extension method to retrieve the claim.

I believe the best place to add the claims would be in the login method.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
         if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);
        // Now model is valid, require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on.
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
                    "You must have a confirmed email to log in.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
                "There is no registered account for the email address supplied.");
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

            // Add claims to signed in user 
            var userClaims = HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList();
            userClaims.Add(new Claim("fullname", user.GetFullName(user.UserName)));
            userClaims.Add(new Claim("avatarUrl", user.AvatarUrl));

           // Using ClaimsTransformer
           // Add claims here for the logged in user using AddUserInfoClaimsAsync extension method
            **var ct = new ClaimsHelpers.ClaimsTransformer();
            var identityWithInfoClaims = await ct.AddUserInfoClaimsAsync(User, user);**

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2Fa), new { returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

But the userClaims variable is always empty

[image: Breakpoint showing empty claim list]

Questions:

1. Why is the claims list empty when the claims were just set?
2. Is there a different type of claim for identity?
3. Is there a better method for doing this?

**UPDATE:**
  I had put a ClaimsTransformer together on some earlier attempts, I can get claims added using that (see the change above in bold in the login controller code) but what do I now do with the ClaimsPrincipal variable identityWithinfoClaims? I can't set User equal to it because User is readonly so how does that object with the claims added get used appropriately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add or transform custom claims, implement and use a custom `ClaimsAuthenticationManager`. [How To: Transform Incoming Claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/how-to-transform-incoming-claims).

```
public class ClaimsTransformationModule : ClaimsAuthenticationManager {  
    public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal) {  
        if (incomingPrincipal != null && incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true) {  
           var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity;
           var user = GetUserData(identity);

           identity.AddClaim(new Claim("fullname", user.GetFullName(user.UserName)));  
           identity.AddClaim(new Claim("avatarUrl", user.AvatarUrl)); 
        }  

        return incomingPrincipal;  
    }  
}
```

Here, `GetUserData()` retrieves the User entity from the DB, given the user name.

Register this transformer in the `web.config`:

```
<system.identityModel>
   <identityConfiguration>
      <claimsAuthenticationManager type="MyProject.ClaimsTransformationModule , MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
   </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

Comment: ...As noted in the post, am using .net core 2. No web config in core. GetUserData is being passed the HttpContext.User principal?

Comment: Sorry, did not see that you use asp.net core. Here is a blog that describes how to configure the claims transformation in this case: [Beware in ASP.NET Core 2.0: Claims transformation might run multiple times](https://brockallen.com/2017/08/30/beware-in-asp-net-core-2-0-claims-transformation-might-run-multiple-times/).

Comment: `GetUserData` gets the `IIdentity identity` from the user principal. User name should be accessible via `identity.Name`.

Comment: Except the principle available from HttpContext.User is a security principal, not a claims principal. i have a ClaimsTransformer set up already, but it needs a ClaimsPrincipal passed in as a parameter. How does the HttpContext.User become a claims principal?

Comment: You just need to register the claims transformer properly, you do not need to use it manually or pass anything to it. See [this blog post](http://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity) on how to get it running in ASP.NET Core. That post also shows you how to use a UserClaimsPrincipalFactory to adjust the claims based on your application user.

Comment: @poke...I read that blog post, but Im using Asp.Net Core 2.0 and the app.UseClaimsTransformation(new ClaimsTransformationOptions
{
    Transformer = new ClaimsTransformer()
});

Comment: That configuration doesnt work in Core 2.0, there is no UseClaimsTransformation any more and I can't find an equivalent method to do this.

Comment: I think Asp.Net Identity a lot more complicated and confusing than it should be.

Answer (score 4):

We encountered exactly the same problem some time ago. 
The solution is rather simple. You just need to create your own implementation of `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory` interface and register it in DI container. Of course, it's not necessary to write the implementation of that interface from scratch - you can derive your class from `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` and just override one method.

Here is a [step-by-step description](https://korzh.com/blogs/net-tricks/aspnet-identity-store-user-data-in-claims) including the code snippets.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `.NET core` Middleware pipeline (or another custom setup) where you handle your `authentication`/`authorization` and instantiate the `Claim` you can directly add it to the `HttpContext` like so (no need for a `ClaimsAuthenticationManager`):

```
HttpContext ctx; // you need to have access to the context
var claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name.Value);
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { claim }, "BasicAuthentication"); // this uses basic auth
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
ctx.User = principal;
```

This example *sets* the `ClaimsIdentity`, if you need to *add* a `Claim` instead you can do that as well.